# Why doesn't laravel-dompdf load font-face for bold?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-blade, php-8.1

I am using laravel-dompdf on my system to output pdfs.

I recently updated php and laravel.

However, some of the pdf's are garbled.

Font is defined by font-face in css.

The font-face is defined in public/assets/pdf.css.

**Characters enclosed in <th> are garbled.**

**Characters with font-weight of "bold" are also garbled.**

Why is this?

The .a class defined in public/assets/pdf.css. is reflected.

It was working without garbled characters in php7.4.33 and laravel6.20.44 before the update.

I heard from a friend that two font-face definitions are needed to support bold in utf-8, so I defined two font-face definitions, but they are not reflected.

The .a class defined in public/assets/pdf.css. is reflected.

**public/assets/pdf.css**

```
.a {
  font-size: 80px;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: mcs;
    src: url('../fonts/mcs.TTF');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: mcs;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: bold;
  src: url('../fonts/mcs.TTF');
}

body {
    font-family: ipag;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

**resources/views/pdf.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="{{ public_path('/assets/pdf.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>カタカナ</th>
            <td>カタカナ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>漢字</th>
            <td>漢字</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ひらがな</th>
            <td>ひらがな</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="a">あいうえお</p>
    <p style="font-weight: bold">あいうえお<p>
</body>
</html>
```

**function in controller**

```
$export = $this->pdf->loadView('pdf');
return $export->download('test.pdf');
```

The TTF file exists without problems in public/fonts/mcs.TTF.

**sh-4.2# php -v**

```
PHP 8.1.23 (cli) (built: Sep 15 2023 21:56:29) (NTS)
```

**sh-4.2# php artisan --version**

```
Laravel Framework 9.52.16
```

and I have installed the mbstring extension.

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

Output pdf
[image: Output pdf]

Comment: You use `font-family: ipag;` on `body`, yet you register the font face with `mcs` name.

Comment: @rizqyhi
Thanks for your comment.
Deleting the body ipag did not work.

Comment: @KJ
Thank you very much.
I see that by setting two font-face settings, it is reflected in the normal font and the bold font.
However, it is not reflected.

Comment: TO:I have no idea about the systems you are running within, as to what fonts they use, but if I as c...
Sorry, I just saw email and noticed your comment.

Comment: I share the final result: updating barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to 2.0.0 caused garbled characters in <th> and bold. 1.0.2 did not cause garbled characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to 1.0.0 and a little later it improved. It is not known why it improved.